# Custom keyboard words suggestion

Tags: android

Is there a way I can change the suggestions the keyboard shows for autocompletion of a word? I want to maintain a separate dictionary in the app and when the user types in the `EditText` he should be shown suggestions from that dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

For changing the suggestions, you will have to implement your own keyboard. This is not what you want to do I believe.

The simplest option for you is to use [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) for showing user the suggestions. Looks something like the following:

[image: AutoCompleteTextView]

Comment: I do not want to show it in the dropdown. I want to show it with the keyboard suggestions.

Comment: Like he said, implement your own keyboard.

Comment: In that case you're out of luck mate AFAIK. Each keyboard is an app that has it's own dictionary that it reads the suggestions from.

Answer (score 3):

After reading several posts, I understood it can not be done without implementing my own keyboard. So, I ended up implementing a layout for displaying suggestions over the keyboard.(i.e. at the bottom of the activity view). When the keyboard shows up it automatically comes over the keyboard.

First, I turned off the default suggestions in the `EditText` using

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Then for detecting if the keyboard is displaying or not:

```
myActivityView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int heightDiff = myActivityView.getRootView().getHeight() - myActivityView.getHeight();
            if (heightDiff > 180) { 
                // if more than 180 then its a keyboard
                showSuggestions();
            }else{
                //keyboard gone... 
                // hide suggestion layout
            }
        }
    });
```

I added a 100ms delay so that the keyboard hides its default suggestion layout, in case it is displaying.

```
private void showSuggestions(){
    myActivityView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mySuggestionLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a tutorial on the Android Development website, which explains this. See the link here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html